# Normalizing long data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm having trouble finding how to normalize data in long form in pandas.  In R, I would cast the data, normalize, then melt.  But I can't work out how to "invert" the pivot_table, here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Declare the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'Machine': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B','C'],
                   'Sensor1': [2.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
                   'Sensor2': [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]        
    })
```

this how `df` looks like

```
    Machine  Sensor1  Sensor2  Time
0       A        2        1     1
1       B        3        1     1
2       C        3        3     1
3       A        4        1     2
4       B        5        1     2
5       C        6        3     2
```

Pivoting

```
# Pivot
dfWide = pd.pivot_table(df,index = 'Time',values=['Sensor1','Sensor2'],columns='Machine')

# Normalize
machines = ['C','B','A'] # Backwards to normalize A last
for m in machines:
    dfWide.loc[:,('Sensor1',m)] = dfWide.loc[:,('Sensor1',m)] / dfWide.loc[:,('Sensor1','A')]
# Revert to original (long) form
```

this is how `dfWide` looks like

```
print(dfWide)
              Sensor1        Sensor2
Machine     A    B    C     A   B   C
Time                        
1           1   1.50  1.5   1   1   3
2           1   1.25  1.5   1   1   3
```

Does anyone know how to complete the last step?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Could you explain what should be the result?

Comment: Yes, please provide desired result. Also, does data frame derive from database? If so, SQL could be a viable solution and avoids restructuring a Python object in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [`pd.melt()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

```
In [134]:
df_melted = pd.melt(dfWide.reset_index() , id_vars=['Time'] , var_name=['Sensors' , 'Machine'])
df_melted
Out[134]:
   Time Sensors Machine value
0   1   Sensor1 A       1.00
1   2   Sensor1 A       1.00
2   1   Sensor1 B       1.50
3   2   Sensor1 B       1.25
4   1   Sensor1 C       1.50
5   2   Sensor1 C       1.50
6   1   Sensor2 A       1.00
7   2   Sensor2 A       1.00
8   1   Sensor2 B       1.00
9   2   Sensor2 B       1.00
10  1   Sensor2 C       3.00
11  2   Sensor2 C       3.00

In [148]:
res = pd.pivot_table(df_melted ,index=['Time' , 'Machine'] , columns=['Sensors']).reset_index()
res
Out[148]:
            Time    Machine      value
Sensors                     Sensor1 Sensor2
0           1           A   1.00    1
1           1           B   1.50    1
2           1           C   1.50    3
3           2           A   1.00    1
4           2           B   1.25    1
5           2           C   1.50    3

In [150]:
res.columns = ['Time' , 'Machine' , 'Sensor1' , 'Sensor2']
res
Out[150]:
  Time  Machine Sensor1 Sensor2
0   1   A       1.00    1
1   1   B       1.50    1
2   1   C       1.50    3
3   2   A       1.00    1
4   2   B       1.25    1
5   2   C       1.50    3
```